# Acquire Twitter request token failed

Tags: c#, oauth, twitter-oauth

I followed the instruction at http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth#request-token, and developed a c# class to do the OAuth authorization. **I used the parameters on the page, and the output signature base string and signature match that on the page. So I think the algorithm part is correct.** Then I replaced the parameters with the ones in my twitter application, but I failed to acquire the request token from Twitter service. And the response data is "Failed to validate oauth signature and token".

Here's the request I send (I used http, instead of https for debug):

```
POST http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: OAuth oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3005%2Fthe_dance%2Fprocess_callback%3Fservice_provider_id%3D11", oauth_consumer_key="GDdmIQH6jhtmLUypg82g", oauth_nonce="QP70eNmVz8jvdPevU3oJD2AfF7R7odC2XJcn4XlZJqk", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1272323042", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signagure="IP%2FEEoc4tKdiobM%2FKH5cPK69cJM%3D"
Host: api.twitter.com
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
```

And here's the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Connection: Keep-Alive
Connection: Proxy-Support
Content-Length: 44
Via: 1.1 APS-PRXY-09
Expires: Tue, 31 Mar 1981 05:00:00 GMT
Date: Fri, 08 Apr 2011 05:47:20 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: hi
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication
Status: 401 Unauthorized
X-Transaction: 1302241640-40339-46793
Last-Modified: Fri, 08 Apr 2011 05:47:20 GMT
X-Runtime: 0.01519
Pragma: no-cache
X-Revision: DEV
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0
Set-Cookie: k=207.46.55.29.1302241640766556; path=/; expires=Fri, 15-Apr-11 05:47:20 GMT; domain=.twitter.com
Set-Cookie: guest_id=13022416407746962; path=/; expires=Sun, 08 May 2011 05:47:20 GMT
Set-Cookie: _twitter_sess=BAh7CDoPY3JlYXRlZF9hdGwrCEiBpjMvAToHaWQiJWMzMTViOGZiNDkzMDRi%250ANjNhMmQwYmVkZDBhNTc2NTc4IgpmbGFzaElDOidBY3Rpb25Db250cm9sbGVy%250AOjpGbGFzaDo6Rmxhc2hIYXNoewAGOgpAdXNlZHsA--177afd5c0f6fe30005ab9a9412e6f85ab03cbfa7; domain=.twitter.com; path=/; HttpOnly
Vary: Accept-Encoding

Failed to validate oauth signature and token
```

This is how I generate the normalized parameters:

```
string.Join("&", (from d in this.BuildParameterDict()
                  select string.Format("{0}={1}", OAuthEncoding.Encode(d.Key), OAuthEncoding.Encode(d.Value))))
```

The *BuildParameterDict* method will sorted build a list with: parameters from query string; parameters from body; parameters sepcific to 'oauth', except the 'oauth_signature'.

Then the signature base string is generated by:

```
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            sb.Append(OAuthEncoding.Encode(this._request.Method));
            sb.Append('&');
            sb.Append(OAuthEncoding.Encode(this.GetNormalUri()));
            sb.Append('&');
            sb.Append(OAuthEncoding.Encode(this.GetNormalParameters()));
```

This is the generated base string with parameters from the above page:

> POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&oauth_callback%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3005%252Fthe_dance%252Fprocess_callback%253Fservice_provider_id%253D11%26oauth_consumer_key%3DGDdmIQH6jhtmLUypg82g%26oauth_nonce%3DQP70eNmVz8jvdPevU3oJD2AfF7R7odC2XJcn4XlZJqk%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1272323042%26oauth_version%3D1.0

which is identical to the string on that page.

Comment: The oauth parameters are request parameters, they don't go in the Authorization header. Put them below the headers.

Comment: But according to [this](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth#request-token), I can use the 'Authorization' header. Also, I tried to put them in the body, does not work either...

Comment: your base string seems ok. how about your hashing? what are you using while creating your signature? key needs to be constructed from OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET and OAUTH_TOKEN. even though the token is missing the key needs to have an & at the end (code is PHP): `$KEY = $OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET.'&'.$OAUTH_TOKEN;` than the signature `$OAUTH_SIGNATURE = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $BASE_STRING, $KEY, true));`... I guess you have a problem with the signature.

Comment: in addition, the string you are creating seems "exactly" the same with Twitter's example. are you not creating an nonce and timestamp yourself? are you using hand written strings? you must provide timestamp as unixtime and the nonce must be random. something like md5 hashing a random big number...

Comment: Yes, the '&' has taken care of. In the above code, I hard coded the 'timespan' and 'nonce', in practice they are replaced with proper value.

Comment: If everything is ok then your problem might be the callback to the localhost. As localhost is actually 127.0.0.1 Twitter may not be returning a token. You can try adding a domain to your hosts file (check http://bit.ly/fVHx6V for hosts), also it is possible for writing your test app for the command prompt without using the callback.

Comment: i tried to change the callback url to my real domain, but it still does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your oauth signature is listed as "oauth_signagure" in your request.

oAuth parameters has to be sorted before sending, but signature has to be at the end of the authorization request.(9.1.1 in http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#anchor14)

You may also need to specify a realm="/oauth/request_token". It's optional, but as I remember correctly Twitter wants this one for a request token.

If you can add your code we might find what's going on, as you might not be building your request and key for signature hashing correctly.

Comment: Thanks for finding that typo :) I will add some code snippet to the original post.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The 'oauth_signature' must comes last. But it is not mentioned [here](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth#request-token), and the example is even wrong...I hate twitter :(