# Twitter OAuth Authorization Issue with .NET (C#)

Tags: c#, oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have been pulling my hair to figure our what goes wrong here and apparently I haven't been able to. I try to create a basic structure to work with Twitter API over OAuth in .NET (C#) but something is wrong and I cannot see what that is.

For example, when I send a [request in order to obtain a request token](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/oauth/request_token), I get back 401 Unauthorized response back with a message as follows:

> Failed to validate oauth signature and token

The signature base that I use to create the signature is as follows (I replaced my actual Consumer Key with a dummy value):

> POST&http%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&oauth_callback%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44444%2Faccount%2Fauth%26oauth_consumer_key%3XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX%26oauth_nonce%3DNjM0NzkyMzk0OTk2ODEyNTAz%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1343631900%26oauth_version%3D1.0

The signing key only consists of my Consumer Key Secret and an ampersand given the fact that I don't have a token secret available yet (again, I replaced my actual Consumer Key with a dummy value):

> signingKey: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&

At the end, I end up with the following Authorization header (again, dummy Consumer Key):

> OAuth oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44444%2Faccount%2Fauth",oauth_consumer_key="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",oauth_nonce="NjM0NzkyMzk0OTk2ODEyNTAz",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1343631900",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="ttLvZ2Xzq4CHt%2BNM4pW7X4h1wRA%3D"

The code I use for this is as follows (it is a little bit long but I'd rather paste it here instead of giving a gist URL or something):

```
public class OAuthMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler {

    private const string OAuthConsumerKey = "oauth_consumer_key";
    private const string OAuthNonce = "oauth_nonce";
    private const string OAuthSignature = "oauth_signature";
    private const string OAuthSignatureMethod = "oauth_signature_method";
    private const string OAuthTimestamp = "oauth_timestamp";
    private const string OAuthToken = "oauth_token";
    private const string OAuthVersion = "oauth_version";
    private const string OAuthCallback = "oauth_callback";

    private const string HMACSHA1SignatureType = "HMAC-SHA1";

    private readonly OAuthState _oAuthState;

    public OAuthMessageHandler(OAuthCredential oAuthCredential, OAuthSignatureEntity signatureEntity,
        IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> parameters, HttpMessageHandler innerHandler) : base(innerHandler) {

        _oAuthState = new OAuthState() {
            Credential = oAuthCredential,
            SignatureEntity = signatureEntity,
            Parameters = parameters,
            Nonce = GenerateNonce(),
            SignatureMethod = GetOAuthSignatureMethod(),
            Timestamp = GetTimestamp(),
            Version = GetVersion()
        };
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {

        //add the auth header
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
            "OAuth", GenerateAuthHeader(_oAuthState, request)
        );

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }

    private string GetTimestamp() {

        TimeSpan timeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        return Convert.ToInt64(timeSpan.TotalSeconds).ToString();
    }

    private string GetVersion() {

        return "1.0";
    }

    private string GetOAuthSignatureMethod() {

        return HMACSHA1SignatureType;
    }

    private string GenerateNonce() {

        return Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()));
    }

    private string GenerateSignature(OAuthState oAuthState, HttpRequestMessage request) {

        //https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/creating-signature
        //http://garyshortblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/11/a-twitter-oauth-example-in-c/

        SortedDictionary<string, string> signatureCollection = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();

        //Required for all requests
        signatureCollection.Add(OAuthConsumerKey, oAuthState.Credential.ConsumerKey);
        signatureCollection.Add(OAuthNonce, oAuthState.Nonce);
        signatureCollection.Add(OAuthVersion, oAuthState.Version);
        signatureCollection.Add(OAuthTimestamp, oAuthState.Timestamp);
        signatureCollection.Add(OAuthSignatureMethod, oAuthState.SignatureMethod);

        //Parameters
        if (oAuthState.Parameters != null) {
            oAuthState.Parameters.ForEach(x => signatureCollection.Add(x.Key, x.Value));
        }

        //Optionals
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(oAuthState.Credential.Token))
            signatureCollection.Add(OAuthToken, oAuthState.Credential.Token);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(oAuthState.Credential.CallbackUrl))
            signatureCollection.Add(OAuthCallback, oAuthState.Credential.CallbackUrl);

        //Build the signature
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        strBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}&", request.Method.Method.ToUpper());
        strBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}&", Uri.EscapeDataString(request.RequestUri.ToString()));
        signatureCollection.ForEach(x =>
            strBuilder.Append(
                Uri.EscapeDataString(string.Format("{0}={1}&", x.Key, x.Value))
            )
        );

        //Remove the trailing ambersand char from the signatureBase.
        //Remember, it's been urlEncoded so you have to remove the
        //last 3 chars - %26
        string baseSignatureString = strBuilder.ToString();
        baseSignatureString = baseSignatureString.Substring(0, baseSignatureString.Length - 3);

        //Build the signing key
        string signingKey = string.Format(
            "{0}&{1}", Uri.EscapeDataString(oAuthState.SignatureEntity.ConsumerSecret),
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(oAuthState.SignatureEntity.OAuthTokenSecret) ? "" : Uri.EscapeDataString(oAuthState.SignatureEntity.OAuthTokenSecret)
        );

        //Sign the request
        using (HMACSHA1 hashAlgorithm = new HMACSHA1(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(signingKey))) {

            return Convert.ToBase64String(
                hashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(
                    new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(baseSignatureString)
                )
            );
        }
    }

    private string GenerateAuthHeader(OAuthState oAuthState, HttpRequestMessage request) {

        SortedDictionary<string, string> sortedDictionary = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();
        sortedDictionary.Add(OAuthNonce, Uri.EscapeDataString(oAuthState.Nonce));
        sortedDictionary.Add(OAuthSignatureMethod, Uri.EscapeDataString(oAuthState.SignatureMethod));
        sortedDictionary.Add(OAuthTimestamp, Uri.EscapeDataString(oAuthState.Timestamp));
        sortedDictionary.Add(OAuthConsumerKey, Uri.EscapeDataString(oAuthState.Credential.ConsumerKey));
        sortedDictionary.Add(OAuthVersion, Uri.EscapeDataString(oAuthState.Version));

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_oAuthState.Credential.Token))
            sortedDictionary.Add(OAuthToken, Uri.EscapeDataString(oAuthState.Credential.Token));

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_oAuthState.Credential.CallbackUrl))
            sortedDictionary.Add(OAuthCallback, Uri.EscapeDataString(oAuthState.Credential.CallbackUrl));

        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        var valueFormat = "{0}=\"{1}\",";

        sortedDictionary.ForEach(x => { 
            strBuilder.AppendFormat(valueFormat, x.Key, x.Value); 
        });

        //oAuth parameters has to be sorted before sending, but signature has to be at the end of the authorization request
        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591240/acquire-twitter-request-token-failed
        strBuilder.AppendFormat(valueFormat, OAuthSignature, Uri.EscapeDataString(GenerateSignature(oAuthState, request)));

        return strBuilder.ToString().TrimEnd(',');
    }

    private class OAuthState {

        public OAuthCredential Credential { get; set; }
        public OAuthSignatureEntity SignatureEntity { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Parameters { get; set; }
        public string Nonce { get; set; }
        public string Timestamp { get; set; }
        public string Version { get; set; }
        public string SignatureMethod { get; set; }
    }
}
```

There is a mix of new .NET `HttpClient` here but the Authorization header generation code is clear to understand.

So, what would be my problem here and what am I missing?

**Edit:**

I gave it a try for different endpoint (such as /1/account/update_profile.json), and it works when I send a request whose body doesn't require encoding. E.g: `location=Marmaris` works but `location=Marmaris, Turkey` doesn't work even if I encode it using `Uri.EscapeDataString`.

**Edit:**

I gave it a try with Twitter OAuth tool to see if there is any particular difference between my signature base and twitter's and I can see that twitter's encoding is different than mine. For example, Twitter produces `location%3DMarmaris%252C%2520Turkey` value for `location=Marmaris, Turkey` but what I produce is `location%3DMarmaris%2C%20Turkey`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity....why aren't you using [DotNetAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) for this?

Comment: @James It is a massive library and it feels like magic when using it which I am not comfortable with. I am happy with the Garbage Collection level magics but not DotNetOpenAuth kinds.

Comment: @tugberk - At the very least compare how DotNetAuth does what you are trying to do.  It seems you don't want to even attempt to understand what it does.

Comment: @Ramhound is that the point of the question or does that answer the question in any way?

Comment: whoever gives a downvote this question should be out of his/her mind. At least have the guts to explain why.

Comment: @tugberk Nice work coming back and editing your post and then following up with the answer. OAuth is tricky and this will hopefully help others who want to write their own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that all the problem was related to encoding issue and for now, it seems that I solved the problem out. Here is a few information about the issue:

When we are creating the signature base, the parameter values needs to be encoded twice. For example, I have a collection as below:

```
var collection = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
collection.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("location", Uri.EscapeDataString(locationVal)));
collection.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("url", Uri.EscapeDataString(profileUrl)));
```

When I pass this to GenerateSignature method, that method encodes these one more time and this results percentage signs to be encoded as `%25` and this made it work. One of my problems was solved but I still couldn't issue a request token request successfully at that time.

Then, I looked at the "request_token" request and saw the below line of code:

```
OAuthCredential creds = new OAuthCredential(_consumerKey) {
    CallbackUrl = "http://localhost:44444/account/auth"
};
```

I was sending the `CallbackUrl` as it is in order for it to be encoded but as twitter needs to encode things twice for the signature base, I thought that might be the problem. Then, I replaced this code with the following one:

```
OAuthCredential creds = new OAuthCredential(_consumerKey) { 
    CallbackUrl = Uri.EscapeDataString("http://localhost:44444/account/auth")
};
```

One more change I made was inside the `GenerateAuthHeader` method since I don't need to encode `CallbackUrl` twice.

```
//don't encode it here again.
//we already did that and auth header doesn't require it to be encoded twice
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_oAuthState.Credential.CallbackUrl))
    sortedDictionary.Add(OAuthCallback, oAuthState.Credential.CallbackUrl);
```

And I made it run w/o any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Tugberk here is another OAuth lib, no magic here.

http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/csharp/OAuthBase.cs

Comment: My implementation is based on that but I encountered some issue with that as well (most probably encoding issues). That's why I need a custom impl.