# How to post Twitter message to authenticated user's timeline via OAuth

Tags: c#, oauth, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-oauth

I've been wrestling with the Twitter API for a few days now but I cannot post a message to an authenticated user's timeline. I've got an ASP.NET MVC 4 application that signs a user in via Twitter and saves the access token that comes back from the sign in process. That part works fine. I can see my application with read and write permissions within the authenticated user's twitter account.

I'm then using that access token, along with the consumer key, consumer secret and oauth token secret associated with my Twitter application, to post to the user's timeline. I'm getting a 401 unauthorised error every time. I've tried using the 1.1 API and the 1 API with the same result.

Most of the code comes from Gary Short's article here: http://garyshortblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/11/a-twitter-oauth-example-in-c/

Here's what I've got so far. If anyone can spot any clues as to what I'm missing I'd be most grateful.

```
    public async Task<bool> Push(TwitterMessage twitterMessage)
    {
        const string updateApi = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json";
        const string oauthConsumerKey = "<consumerKey>";
        const string consumerSecret = "<consumerSecret>";
        const string oauthSignatureMethod = "HMAC-SHA1";
        const string oauthTokenSecret = "<tokenSecret>";
        var signingKey = string.Format("{0}&{1}", consumerSecret.Escaped(), oauthTokenSecret.Escaped());

        var postBody = "status=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(twitterMessage.MessageContent);
        var oauthNonce = Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()));
        var oauthToken = "<authenticatedUserToken>";
        var timeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        var oauthTimestamp = Convert.ToInt64(timeSpan.TotalSeconds).ToString();

        var message = string.Format("POST {0}?{1} HTTP/1.1", updateApi, postBody.Escaped());
        var hasher = new HMACSHA1(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(signingKey));
        var signatureString = Convert.ToBase64String(hasher.ComputeHash(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(message)));

        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(updateApi);
        request.KeepAlive = false;

        var authorisationBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        authorisationBuilder.Append("OAuth ");
        authorisationBuilder.AppendFormat("oauth_consumer_key=\"{0}\",", oauthConsumerKey.Escaped());
        authorisationBuilder.AppendFormat("oauth_signature_method=\"{0}\",", oauthSignatureMethod.Escaped());
        authorisationBuilder.AppendFormat("oauth_timestamp=\"{0}\",", oauthTimestamp.Escaped());
        authorisationBuilder.AppendFormat("oauth_nonce=\"{0}\",", oauthNonce.Escaped());
        authorisationBuilder.AppendFormat("oauth_token=\"{0}\",", oauthToken.Escaped());
        authorisationBuilder.AppendFormat("oauth_signature=\"{0}\"", signatureString.Escaped());
        var authorisation = authorisationBuilder.ToString();
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorisation);

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        using (var stream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
        {
            var bodyBytes = new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(postBody);
            stream.Write(bodyBytes, 0, bodyBytes.Length);
        }

        //Allow us a reasonable timeout in case Twitter's busy
        request.Timeout = 3 * 60 * 1000;

        try
        {
            var response = await request.GetResponseAsync() as HttpWebResponse;
            return true;
        }
        catch (WebException)
        {
            return false;
        } 
    }

    public static string Escaped(this string input)
    {
        return Uri.EscapeDataString(input);
    }
```

**UPDATE** Looking at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12198734/getting-twitter-access-secret-using-dotnetopenauth-in-mvc4) it looks like I can't use the DotNetOpenAuth twitter client for authorisation, which I had been doing. The suggestion there is to extend the twitter consumer class instead to perform the authorisation, which will allow me to retrieve the user's token secret (the missing piece of my puzzle I think). Will post another update when I get this working.

Comment: Have you gone line by line to make sure what you send to the server is what you should be sending?

Comment: I've used the Twitter API console to make some requests and verified that I'm sending exactly the same data as those. It may be that I need to add more info into the post request then I'm sending but I'm not sure

Comment: How did you verify your sending the same data exactly?  Did you verify right before you sent the data, the data that was pending, was exactly the same?  You must be doing something different if your getting an authorisation error.

Comment: I stuck a breakpoint on the `var response = await request.GetResponseAsync() as HttpWebResponse;` line and had a look at the authorisation and post body values. Everything seemed to be in order but I may not be posting the right data. I've seen replies to other SO posts stating things like server times not being synchronised to Twitter causing issues but I'm running this locally and thing my server clock is accurate.

Comment: Looking at this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11717144/twitter-oauth-authorization-issue-with-net-c) it could be related to encoding - will check that out when I get back to the project this evening.

Comment: Sounds like you have debugging to do to verify your sending the correct data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is an issue with DotNetOpenAuth as it currently stands. For Twitter authentication, the DotNetOpenAuth client doesn't allow for the full authorisation flow (needed for posting to a user's timeline). Only the access token is retrieved from the initial handshake and not the access token secret. I was using the access token secret associated with my Twitter app, rather than the Twitter user who was signing in, so authorisation was failing every time.

UPDATE: I've finally gone with using [Daniel Crenna's `Tweetsharp`](https://github.com/danielcrenna/vault/tree/master/tweetsharp) library, which makes the code a little simpler than writing my own API wrapper would have been:

```
public async Task<bool> Push(TwitterAccount account)
{
    var twitterService = new TwitterService(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
    twitterService.AuthenticateWith(account.AccessToken, account.AccessTokenSecret);
    var options = new SendTweetOptions {Status = string.Format("{0} {1}", account.Message.MessageContent, account.Message.ShortLink)};
    var status = twitterService.SendTweet(options);
    return status != null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code and link/article simple and easy :

```
protected void btnTweet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 string oauthAccessToken = Session["twtoken"].ToString();
 string oauthAccessTokenSecret = Session["twsecret"].ToString();

 OAuthHelper oauthhelper = new OAuthHelper();
 oauthhelper.TweetOnBehalfOf(oauthAccessToken, oauthAccessTokenSecret, txtTweet.Text);

 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(oauthhelper.oauth_error))
      Response.Write("Twit Posted Successfully");
 else
      Response.Write(oauthhelper.oauth_error);
}
```

Read more how to get access token and secret key and download OAuthHelper and OAuthUtility Class below is the link -

*[How to post tweet on behalf of an user from asp.net using oauth authentication](http://www.dotnetbull.com/2013/06/tweet-on-behalf-of-user-from-aspnet.html)*

*[Login with twitter using oauth authentication in asp.net and get access token, screen name and userid](http://www.dotnetbull.com/2013/05/login-with-twitter-using-oauth.html)*